Why inputs with related location table has empty values?
In laravel 10 / filamentphp 3 app in editor of branch I need also to show/edit
fields from related location table with relations in app/Models/Branch.php :
public function location()
{
    return $this->morphOne(related: Location::class, name: 'model');
}

and in app/Models/Location.php :
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo;

class Location extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'locations';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [ 'country', 'place', 'lng', 'lat' ];

    public function branchable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo(name: 'place', type: 'App\Models\Branch');
    }

    public function employeeable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo(name: 'place', type: 'App\Models\Employee');
    }
    ...
}

In branch resource I read data with related location
public static function getEloquentQuery(): Builder
{
    return parent::getEloquentQuery()->with('location');
}


if to dump data in branch resource:

public static function getEloquentQuery(): Builder
{
    dd(parent::getEloquentQuery()->with('location')->get());
    return parent::getEloquentQuery()->with('location');
}

I see that in Branch model "location" is inside "relations"   :

and in form inputs for location :
->schema([
    TextInput::make('location.place')->lazy()
        ->required()
        ->minLength(3)
        ->maxLength(100)
        ->placeholder('Enter place of location'),
    TextInput::make('location.lat')->lazy()
        ->required()
        ->numeric()
        ->minLength(3)
        ->maxLength(100)
        ->placeholder('Enter valid lat value'),
    TextInput::make('location.lng')->lazy()
        ->required()
        ->numeric()
        ->minLength(3)
        ->maxLength(100)
        ->placeholder('Enter valid lng value '),

Are empty. What to fix to see data in related location group?

I made it using afterStateHydrated method :
TextInput::make('location.place')->lazy()
    ->afterStateHydrated(function (TextInput $component, $state) use ($isInsert) {
        $branchModel = $component->getModelInstance();
        $locationModel = $branchModel->location;
        if ( ! empty($locationModel->place)) { // Fill place field only in "edit" mode
            $component->state($locationModel->place);
        }
    })
    ->required()
    ->minLength(3)
    ->maxLength(100)
    ->placeholder('Enter place of location'),

it works ok.
